# Spring Boot application runs on localhost but returns 404 on external Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat, spring-security

I have created a Spring Boot application, with Spring Security, to expose some REST API endpoints.
I've created the project using the built in IntelliJ Ultimate Spring Initializr.

Spring version: 2.4.4
Type: Maven
Java version: 8
Packaging: War

When I run the application from within IntelliJ and it starts an instance of Tomcat 9.0.44.
Then I created a WAR file, using maven>package, to test in on my PC's local XAMPP installation. (*I use Tomcat 8.5.53. The reason is that this is the Tomcat version that is available at our production environment to which I finally want to deploy.*)
I deployed using the tomcat manager, and it runs without any problem there as well.
I then moved the war to our production server and used the Tomcat manager UI to deploy.
I can see in the manager that it deployed and that it is running.
**Production server Tomcat Manager UI**
[image]

When I tried to access my endpoints, using Postman, no matter what endpoint I try to access I always get a 404 error...

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.apiauthentication</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>FLEET_Authentication_Server</name>
    <description>Authentication Server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.10.6</jjwt.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**main class-AuthServerApplication**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below are the entries in the Tomcat logs

**catalina.log**

```
21-Apr-2021 08:14:09.860 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/auth-server.war
21-Apr-2021 08:14:11.828 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Apr-2021 08:14:16.257 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/auth-server.war has finished in 6,397 ms
```

**localhost.log**

```
21-Apr-2021 08:14:11.839 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
21-Apr-2021 08:14:13.419 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

**manager.log**

```
21-Apr-2021 08:12:04.977 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2623] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
21-Apr-2021 08:14:09.806 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: install: Installing web application '/auth-server' from '/tmp-war/auth-server.war'
21-Apr-2021 08:14:16.257 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2726] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
```

In the **localhost_access_log** file I can see no entries for my attempts to access the newly deployed application.

Some things that I have tried:

- Extend SpringBootServletInitializer on my main class and override the configure method

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthServerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AuthServerApplication.class);
    }
}
```

- Add start-class in the properties section of the pom.xml

```xml
    <properties>
        ...
        <start-class>
            com.apiauthentication.authserver.AuthServerApplication
        </start-class>
    </properties>
```

- Add an exclusion to the spring-boot-starter-web, for spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

- And different combinations of those things as well

Anyone has any hints as to what might be the problem?
Basically I can run on my local XAMPP but not on the production server

Comment: What seems strange is the lack of entries in the access log. Are your sure that your production server is not behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Thank you! The problem was proxy related....  The server is used to host multiple domains, managed by Plesk. I had to go to the domain's Apache settings and set up new ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the comment from [Piotr P. Karwasz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11748454/piotr-p-karwasz) as the answer.

> What seems strange is the lack of entries in the access log. Are your sure that your production server is not behind a reverse proxy?

The problem was that I was trying to access the application using the domain name, but since the domain was managed using Plesk, and there are other domains on that server as well, I had to go to the Apache settings of the domain and add some new ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse directives, for HTTP and HTTPS